# Regular Expression to eliminate unwanted carriage returns is too slow in the C# script task

Tags: c#, regex, ssis

I have a .csv file which has a Comments column. This column contains carriage returns and line feeds for some of the rows. Due to this the load process fails (it is being loaded through SSIS packages). 
I have added a script task to remove the unwanted carriage returns and line feeds from the file (retaining the one at the end of each row).

I am using the below code to do this. The problem I am facing is that the code runs fine with a small file but it takes too long to run for a big file (more than 1 hour for 37k records with the structure shown in the sample file attached).

I am very new to the C# scripting and hence I am not able to optimize the regular expression used in the script task.
Is there any better way of writing the regular expression so that it runs faster?

Code being used:

```
string myFileData;

string FilePath = Dts.Variables["FilePath"].Value.ToString(); //source file path
string DestinationFilePath = Dts.Variables["DestinationFilePath"].Value.ToString(); //destination file path

const string delimeters = @"\s(?!(([^""]*""){2})*[^""]*$)"; //string pattern to be used in regular expression

myFileData = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);

if (Regex.IsMatch(myFileData, delimeters))
{
    File.WriteAllText(DestinationFilePath, Regex.Replace(myFileData, delimeters, " "));
}
```

Sample Data:

```
    Seminar,Seminar Date,Location,First name,Last name,Comments
    Test Seminar,13/10/2014,Sydney,TEST1_FN,TEST1_LN,This is Test1
    Test Seminar,13/10/2014,Sydney,TEST2_FN,TEST2_LN,This is Test2
    Test Seminar,13/10/2014,Sydney,TEST3_FN,TEST3_LN,This is Test3
    Test Seminar,13/10/2014,Sydney,TEST4_FN,TEST4_LN,"This

is

    Test4"
    Test Seminar,13/10/2014,Sydney,TEST5_FN,TEST5_LN,This is Test5
```

Comment: What do you want to replace? It's no clear from regex

Answer (score 0):

Declare your regex ad field and set Compiled option:

```
_regex = new Regex(@"\s(?!(([^""]*""){2})*[^""]*$)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

And use it:

```
_regex.Replace(myFileData, " ");
```

It'll be a little faster.
Also, don't check before replace - remove your `if` statement, because `Replace` also does it.

Comment: Thanks Backs. Even though the performance has improved but it is still taking around 35-45 min to process these many records (from over an hour earlier).

Comment: I put the if statement to ensure that the whole replace code works only for those files which have such data. For correct files it should not run the replace bit. If I remove the if statement, will it not run the code to replace the contents for every file?

Comment: @Amit of couse, in replace method regex will check is there is something to replace

Comment: This has not still resulted in considerable improvements. The reason why I have the if block is to make sure that a 'clean' copy of the file is only created if there are any records to be replaced. Without the if clause it would create a copy of the file always. My bigger problem is that we load multiple files (with different file structures) through one generic SSIS package. Most of these files are correct. My fix should quickly identify if the file needs to replaced or not. With my current code it takes around 15-18 min even for the clean file without any extra carriage returns